# Why is an extra qualification for inline definitions of member functions disallowed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

If we look at the grammar of a member declaration it loosk something like this:

```
member-declaration:
       function-definition ;

function-definition:
       attribute-specifier-seqopt decl-specifier-seqopt declarator 
       virt-specifier-seqopt function-body

declarator:
       noptr-declarator parameters-and-qualifiers trailing-return-type
```

This disallows the syntax:

```
struct B {
    A B::*B::read();
};
```

Why doesn't it allow an optional `nested-name-specifier ::` before the function name?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would that syntax do?

Comment: @Columbo Make copy/pasting and code generation easier.

Comment: No, what would that particular declaration above - if allowed - actually declare? A function `read` returning a… ?

Comment: @user4331982 but in struct B, you declare member functions of B.  If you would nest a type, you would declare its member function in the nested type.  THis kind of syntax would only improve confusion !

Comment: That solely applies to **local** classes. Please read the paragraphs that you quote more carefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The grammar does not forbid to declare entities named by *nested-name-specifier*s at all.
 As a matter of fact, it has to - for `friend` declarations:

```
class A
{
     friend void OtherNamespace::foo();
};
```

This is a *member-declaration* with the declaration specifier `friend`. It's covered through (bold emphasis mine):

> *member-declaration*:
>       *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *decl-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> ***member-declarator-list***<sub>opt</sub> ;

And

> *member-declarator*:
>        ***declarator*** virt-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> *pure-specifier*<sub>opt</sub>

Now, a declarator has the following grammar:

> *declarator*:
>        *ptr-declarator*
>
> *ptr-declarator*:
>        *noptr-declarator*
>
> *noptr-declarator*:
>        *declarator-id*
>
> *declarator-id*:
>        `...`<sub>opt</sub> *id-expression*

Finally, an id-expression is

> *id-expression*:
>       ***qualified-id***

Comment: However, using a *qualified-id* in OP's code is still banned, by [dcl.meaning]/p1.